# PHP $_GET with HTML

Tags: php, html

I have a index.html file that have the following:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <form action="email.php" method="get">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        </html>
```

And a email.php file with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
       Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
       Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

However I'm getting this:

```
Welcome 
Your email address is:
```

whenever I run it using Brackets and typing into the input. Both of the files are in the same folder. How come what I typed are not showing? What am I doing wrong? Currently just started learning PHP. 
Thanks.

Comment: What URLs are showing in the location bar?

Comment: You have to click on submit button after filling form

Comment: I did submit it.. After I submit it the url is /.../email.php?name=asdf&email=asdf
The "asdf" are what I typed however it's not showing up in the browser.

Comment: Are you running a php server? For example WAMP or XAMPP ?

Comment: Hmm I'm just using brackets and using its "Live preview" feature, so I guess no? Do I need to? I thought Brackets would be enough.

Comment: when you press submit button `email.php` needs to display display name and email

Comment: you never echo post or get directly to page its called XSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is from [W3 schools same code mentioned here for demo](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) they have server to run their page so you need server to run **PHP** file while running in localhost

**Php** is server side application so you need to have server like **Wampserver** [Here is full tutorials installing and running **PHP**](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php1p3.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct.
But you must install wampserver and copy your file(like that's name is stack) to "www" foldre in "C:\wamp\www".
After, run by localhost like "localhost/stack/main.php" in browser address bar.

Answer (score 2):

To further answer this, PHP is a server-side language, so unless your editor has the ability to run PHP (and you have it set up to point to your local PHP copy), the live view feature will likely only work with client-side languages, like Javascript.

You need to install a server like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) as suggested above.